# jQuery: Delayed replacing of a div's innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, innerhtml

I'm trying to use jQuery to fade out an element, replace its `innerHTML` and fade it back in after the content has been replaced. Replacing the content of the element using the `.html()`-method along with the `.find()`-method works, but as soon as I am trying to add a delay to the function that is finding and placing the `innerHTML`, it stops working. This is my code so far:

`'#current-title'` is the element of which the content is supposed to be replaced; `'#title1'` contains the text which is supposed to end up in `'#current-title'`. All of this should happen with a transitioned opacity change of `'#current-title'` before and after the new text has been placed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.replace = function() {

  $('#current-title').css("opacity", "0");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#current-title').html($(this).find('#title1').html());
  }, 500);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#current-title').css("opacity", "1");
  }, 1000);

  alert('Title has been replaced.');
  };

  $(".replace-btn").click(function() {
    $.replace();
  });
});
```

A reduced version of the same function, only replacing the `html` of `'#current-title'` without a `setTimeout`, works just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.replace = function() {

    $('#current-title').html($(this).find('#title1').html());

    alert('Title has been replaced.');
  };

  $(".replace-btn").click(function() {
    $.replace();
  });
});
```

Why is the `setTimeout` in my first piece of code not working?

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.replaceDelayed = function() {

    $('#current-title').css("opacity", "0");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#current-title').html($(this).find('#title1').html());
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#current-title').css("opacity", "1");
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('Title has been replaced.');
    }, 1000);
  };

  $(".replace-btn").click(function() {
    $.replaceDelayed();
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $.replaceNormal = function() {

    $('#current-title').html($(this).find('#title1').html());

    alert('Title has been replaced.');
  };

  $(".replace-btn2").click(function() {
    $.replaceNormal();
  });
});
```

```css
.title {
  visibility: hidden;
}

* {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="current-title">
  <a>Project Title #0</a>
</div>

<br>

<div class="title" id="title1">
  <a>Project Title #1</a>
</div>

<br>

<button class="replace-btn">
  Replace Title (with delay)
</button>

<button class="replace-btn2">
  Replace Title (without delay)
</button>
```

Comment: can we have html code?

Comment: @ChandraShekhar sure, hang on, I'll set up a jsfiddle and add it to the question

Comment: @JoSch Stackoverflow has a build in fiddle that you can use. Wich will be better and easier for people to awnser your question.

Comment: @Granny : strange thing may be but i still like jsfiddle more!

Comment: @Granny I tried using the build-in fiddle, but it keeps crashing when running it. It works fine on jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/johschmoll/6xk8pv25/), so I have added that to the question for now

Comment: There is definitely something strange going on there. Embedding your code as a stacksnippet hangs the page. See the revision history if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48518673/4

Comment: Your code seems to be working just fine. I am not getting the issue you are describing.

Comment: @JoSch You don't need to handle the opacity or the timeout yourself, my answer basically uses only 3 lines of jQuery code: fadeOut, html, fadeIn, job done. No need for JSFiddle either, run the code snippet to see it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, without `setTimeout`, `this` refers to the `window` object. `window.find` will search for a string in the current window. It will not search for the element in the document. [Refer this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find)

`this` inside the setTimeout` method returns a function object.

So your code works after removing `this`.

This works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.replaceDelayed = function() {

    $('#current-title').css("opacity", "0");

    setTimeout(function() {
      //console.log(this) returns the window object
      $('#current-title').html($('#title1').html());
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#current-title').css("opacity", "1");
    }, 1000);


  };

  $(".replace-btn").click(function() {
    $.replaceDelayed();
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $.replaceNormal = function() {
    //console.log(this); returns a function object
    $('#current-title').html($('#title1').html());

    alert('Title has been replaced.');
  };

  $(".replace-btn2").click(function() {
    $.replaceNormal();
  });
});
```

```css
.title {
  visibility: hidden;
}

* {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="current-title">
  <a>Project Title #0</a>
</div>

<br>

<div class="title" id="title1">
  <a>Project Title #1</a>
</div>

<br>

<button class="replace-btn">
  Replace Title (with delay)
</button>

<button class="replace-btn2">
  Replace Title (without delay)
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example that uses [jQuery.fadeOut](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) then [jQuery.fadeIn](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $( "p" ).click(function() {
    ++count;
    $this = $(this);
    $this.fadeOut(500, function() {
      $this.html("Project Title #" + count);
      $this.fadeIn(500);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Project Title #0</p>
```

Run the code snippet, then every time you click the project title, it fades out, its number gets incremented, fades back in.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.replaceDelayed = function() {

    $('#current-title').css("opacity", "0");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#current-title').html($(document).find('#title1').html());
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#current-title').css("opacity", "1");
    }, 800);

    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('Title has been replaced.');
    }, 1000);
  };

  $(".replace-btn").click(function() {
    $.replaceDelayed();
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $.replaceNormal = function() {

    $('#current-title').html($(document).find('#title1').html());

    alert('Title has been replaced.');
  };

  $(".replace-btn2").click(function() {
    $.replaceNormal();
  });
});
```

```css
.title {
  visibility: hidden;
}

* {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="current-title">
  <a>Project Title #0</a>
</div>

<br>

<div class="title" id="title1">
  <a>Project Title #1</a>
</div>

<br>

<button class="replace-btn">
  Replace Title (with delay)
</button>

<button class="replace-btn2">
  Replace Title (without delay)
</button>
```

Here `$(this)` referes to Window Object. To get a handler You Need to Use `$(document)` object

give this a try

Comment: `$.replaceNormal` causes Chrome to crash.

Comment: @Turnip try this

Comment: Working now...  